# Prevent TopAppBar moving out of the screen when keyboard opens

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-softkeyboard, appbar

Am I missing something, but why Scaffold's TopAppBar moves out of the screen when keyboard appears?

I have a simple [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVEKB.jpg):

```
setContent {
  MyTheme {
      Scaffold(topBar = { MyTopAppBar() }) {
         ScaffoldContent(it)
      }
   }
}
```

Where ScaffoldContent is just a Column with a TextField.

When I press a TextField, keyboard opens and [moves everything up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgtQY.jpg) . How can I make the bar stick at the top?

Tried:

1. android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" or "adjustPan"
2. Instead of Scaffold use a Column and add elements there, but moves anyway

Expected:
TopAppBar to be at the top all the time, like in our Views system

Comment: Any luck with this? I am getting the exact same issue.

Comment: No, I did what everybody does: moved a TextField to the top

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?